# Mysql empty table join fails

Tags: mysql, null, left-join

Background, I have a cron job that queries keywords associated with posts, if that keyword is found, a user is emailed about the post.

The cron job runs every minute so once a user has been emailed that notification should not happen again.
The following query runs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS post_id, u.display_name, u.id AS user_id, u.email, k.keyword, k.id AS keyword_id
FROM posts p, user_subscriptions us, keywords_users ku, keywords k, users u
LEFT JOIN keyword_subscription_sent kss ON kss.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN keywords_posts kp ON kss.post_id = kp.post_id
WHERE us.keywords = 1
AND ku.user_id = u.id
AND ku.keyword_id = k.id
AND kp.keyword_id = k.id
#AND kss.user_id IS NULL AND kss.post_id IS NULL
LIMIT 0, 200
```

The query works as expected when the table keywords_posts kp is populated.

If the table keywords_posts kp is empty the query will never return anything.
I attempted to fix this by adding to the WHERE clause:

```
AND kss.user_id IS NULL AND kss.post_id IS NULL
```

But adding this to the WHERE clause will cause the query to never return anything at all at any time.

The desired result is:

The query will return all rows except listed in the keywords_posts kp table.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: If keyword_posts is empty surely this part of your WHERE clause: `AND kp.keyword_id = k.id` will always fail, giving you no results? I think you probably want `kp.keyword_id IS NULL` instead.

Comment: Move that line to the ON clause

Comment: Hi.  [mcve] please.Your "desired" description is unclear. All rows of what? Please use enough words, phrases & sentences to say what you mean. Don't try to cram just some fragments of that into one sentence. Comma binds looser than explicit joins; so the commas are being executed after the left joins. [Learn what left join on returns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091641/3404097): inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Why are you even left joining?--your desired result as a function of input is unclear but it doesn't seem to involve null-extended rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello vveryone and thanks for you input.

The following worked:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT u.id as user_id, u.email, u.display_name, k.id as keyword_id, k.keyword, p.id AS post_id, kp.post_id AS kp_post_id, kp.keyword_id AS kp_keyword_id,
ku.user_id AS ku_user_id, ku.keyword_id AS ku_keyword_id
FROM users u, keywords k, posts p, keywords_posts kp, user_subscriptions us, keywords_users ku
WHERE kp.post_id = p.id AND us.keywords = 1 AND kp.keyword_id = k.id AND ku.keyword_id = k.id AND u.id = ku.user_id
GROUP BY kp.post_id, u.id) AS ukp LEFT JOIN keyword_subscription_sent kss ON ukp.user_id = kss.user_id AND kss.post_id = ukp.post_id WHERE kss.post_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

Relocate the conditions that require a column to be non-NULL from the `WHERE` clause up to the appropriate `ON` clause of the outer join.

Don't mix the old-school comma syntax (for the join operation) with the `JOIN` keyword syntax. Ditch the comma syntax and just use `JOIN`. And move join conditions to the `ON` clause.

---

Moving the condition to the ON clause of the outer join will allow NULL values to be returned.

If we do it the WHERE clause, note that the condition

```
WHERE ( col = some_non_null_val AND col IS NULL )
```

is guaranteed to never evaluate to TRUE. (The condition is checked for each individual row.)  Only rows where the condition evaluate to TRUE will be returned.  Likely you meant to use `OR` in place of `AND`.

But we can avoid that `OR` if we just relocate the condition

```
         col = some_non_null_val
```

to the `ON` clause of the outer join.

---

I hesitate to provide an example query as a demonstration. The original query is producing a semi-Cartesian product; for example what appears to be a cross join between `users` and `user_subscriptions`... the only criteria for matching to `user_subscriptions` is `keywords=1`. So I'm not understanding the specification.

OP reports that query is returning a correct result, but I'm suspicious that the query doesn't actually satisfy the intended specification. I suspect that the matching between `users` and `user_subscriptions` should include some additional criteria.

Without a more precise specification, including sample data and an example of expected output, I cannot in good conscience provide example SQL for OP use-case.

Answer (score 0):

i think kp_keyword_id=k.id from your WHERE condition cause the query to return nothing where kp is empty,try to put that in JOIN instead so it become like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS post_id, u.display_name, u.id AS user_id, u.email, k.keyword, k.id AS keyword_id
FROM posts p, user_subscriptions us, keywords_users ku, keywords k, users u
LEFT JOIN keyword_subscription_sent kss ON kss.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN keywords_posts kp ON kss.post_id = kp.post_id AND kp.keyword_id = k.id 
WHERE us.keywords = 1
AND ku.user_id = u.id
AND ku.keyword_id = k.id
LIMIT 0, 200
```

Comment: I think the part about explicit JOINs is important too, because of the order in which implicit joins are evaluated

Comment: And note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless